# how to add up the current score, jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a current score to add up every time an answer is correct, what is happening is that I have the questions in a pagination set up and when this answer is correct it give me the score but then when it goes to the next page it refresh the score and if I got that one right it just give me the score for that one again but it doesn't add up.

JS code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#author').on('change', function(event) {
    var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
    var correct = $(opt).text().match (arr2);
    var score = 0;   
    if (correct){
      alert('Good job ' + arr2,);
      score += 2;
      alert (score);
      currentScore = score++;
      alert(currentScore);
      display(currentScore);
   } 
   else {
     alert ('nice try ' + arr2);
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `score` and `currentScore` ?? What is `currentScore = score++;` supposed to do?

Comment: score should be 2 points for each correct answer, current score should be the sum of the answers points as you go answering them.

Comment: Where is your `currentScore` variable kept?

Comment: There is where I kept it, I don't know how to kept anywhere else. all that you see there is what I have done with score and current score.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option - local storage.

Here is a reference [W3School Web storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

It's not the most ideal solution, but it can meet your criteria.

```
let score = localStorage.getItem('score')
score++;
localStorage.setItem('score', score);
```

Your pages will be able to access the localStorage so you can get the value of score and re-set it.

Hopefully the reference can answer further questions, else leave a comment!

Con: It may not be supported by all browsers.

EDIT:
Here is an example with your code.

```
$(function() {
  let currentScore = localStorage.getItem('score'); // get score
  if (currentScore === null){   // if score doesnt exist yet
    localStorage.setItem('score', 0);  // set score
    currentScore = 0;       // make currentScore 0
  }

  $('#author').on('change', function(event) {
    var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
    var correct = $(opt).text().match (arr2);         
    if (correct){
      alert('Good job ' + arr2);
      currentScore += 2;    //increment current score by 2
      alert (currentScore);
      localStorage.setItem('score', currentScore);     // set the item again with new value
      alert(currentScore);
      display(currentScore);
   } 
   else {
     alert ('nice try ' + arr2);
   }
  });
});
```

Edit 2:

```
let currentScore = localStorage.getItem('score'); // get score
currentScore = parseInt(currentScore);
```

Comment: can you put my code with that code in it I don't seem to be able to make it work.

Comment: is it suppose to add the numbers like these: 2, 22, 222, 2222. because that is what is doing. Just asking if that is what it is suppose to do?

Comment: That is what is doing

Comment: Oh I see - try and use the `parseInt()` function where it turns it from a string to an int.

Comment: it gave me this (NaN)

Answer (score 0):

> it give me the score but then when it goes to the next page it refresh the score and if I got that one right it just give me the score for that one again but it doesn't add up.

I think your problem is there.

If I understand correctly, when the answer is good, the page refresh and passes to the next question. Your problem is that the score doesn't add up to the previous one.

The `score` variable is only stored in the current page, like a temporary one. Without saving the score on the server, via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or another method, and getting it on the next page, it will not add up. Indeed, `score` will have a value of 0 due to the refresh.

A simple schema  :

score = 0 -> correct answer -> +50 point -> score = 50 -> next page -> score = 0

As you can see, because the javascript you wrote is not assuring the persistance of your information, the previously stored score is lost.

You need to send the score on the server and then get it back when the new page is loaded or to avoid changing page and make your quizz on one and only page, without refreshing.

Keep in mind that everytime you are refresing a page, the javascript is starting again and therefore everything done before is lost.

I hope this was helpful.

Ps: You should place your code in the `$( document ).ready();` block just like this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

It will make your code start when the html DOM (the structure of the html file) is loaded and ready to be manipulated. It can avoid a lot of errors.
Edit2 : What it will look like in your code :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

   $('#author').on('change', function(event) {
      var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
      var correct = $(opt).text().match (arr2);
      var score = 0;   
      if (correct){
        alert('Good job ' + arr2,);
        score += 2;
        alert (score);
        currentScore = score++;
        alert(currentScore);
        display(currentScore);
      } 
      else {
        alert ('nice try ' + arr2);
      }
   });

});
```

Or, to make this more readable and to avoird having a lot of things in the document.ready block (when you will have a lot of lines/functions) :

```
$( document ).ready( myNiceFunction() );

var myNiceFunction = function(){
    $('#author').on('change', function(event) {
    var opt = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ];
    var correct = $(opt).text().match (arr2);
    var score = 0;   
    if (correct){
       alert('Good job ' + arr2,);
       score += 2;
       alert (score);
       currentScore = score++;
       alert(currentScore);
       display(currentScore);
    } 
    else {
       alert ('nice try ' + arr2);
    }
}
```

Ps2 : I know this is not the best website to explain it but I think it is simple enough to make you understand the principle of ajax without losing you into a bunch of technical stuff : [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)

Edit : Grammar and second post-scriptum.

Comment: you are absolutely right in what my problem is, you understand it perfectly,  a lot of people have suggested ajax I just don't know how to use ajax and specially how to use it with the code that I wrote, But what you said interest me and I would like to try it. where should I put the $document ready block in the beginning of what I have or at the end.

Comment: the `ready` function usually is placed at/near the top of your javascript code

Comment: in my code should I put it after my function or on top of it?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to integrate the document.ready block into your code. Christheoreo's answer is great and simple to resolve your problem. However if you want to learn more about javascript and ajax, do not hesitate to do tutorials and to read the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you're doing pagination but it should be ajaxed, instead of a full postback, so you don't lose the values on your page.

Comment: I have no experience with ajax, can you point me in the right direction of where to find information that may help me with this,